# Writing a loop for getting the output to different sheets from oracle database to excel

Tags: excel, oracle10g, excel-2007, vba

I have different column names in a table in an Oracle database and I am fetching the data from    oracle database to excel using VB macro and sorting the data with different column names to different sheets

Currently I wrote a seperate code for each sheet but I want to loop that so the code will be easy.There are 60 collabnames and all are different names and I want to sort them to 60 different sheet

So if I loop it I need not write the same code 60 times

CURRENT CODE:

```
    cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=USERID" & _
    ";Password=PASSWORD" & _
    ";Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")


    rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like 'COLLAB_NAME1' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn
    With Sheet1
            col = 0
             'First Row: names of columns
            Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
                col = col + 1
            Loop


            mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
            .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData




        End With
        rs.Close

  rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like 'COLLAB_NAME_2' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn
    With Sheet2
            col = 0
             'First Row: names of columns
            Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
                col = col + 1
            Loop


            mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
            .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData




        End With
        rs.Close

 rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like 'COLLAB_NAME1_NAME2_3' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn
    With Sheet3
            col = 0
             'First Row: names of columns
            Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
                col = col + 1
            Loop


            mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
            .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData




        End With
        rs.Close
    End Sub
```

NEW CODE:

```
Sub Load_data()
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim col As Integer
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim Query As String
        Dim mtxData As Variant


        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

     cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=USERID" & _
    ";Password=PASSWORD" & _
    ";Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxx" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")

       'Creates an Array with all the Collabnames.

Dim arrayCOLLABNAME(59) As String
Dim idx As Integer
idx = 0
Sheets("COLLABNAME").Select
Range("A1").Select
Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset((idx), 0) = ""
    arrayCOLLABNAME(idx) = ActiveCell.Offset(idx, 0).Value
    idx = idx + 1
Loop
'The name of the First Sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
'Loop for 60 Sheets
For i = 0 To 60
    'adds the new Sheet
    Sheets.Add
    rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like '" & arrayCOLLABNAME(idx) & "' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn
    'use the new Sheet for inserting the Data
    With ActiveSheet
        col = 0
        'First Row: names of columns
        Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData

    End With
    rs.Close
Next i


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that could work for you. But i don't had the time to test it.

****new Code

```
    'Creates an Array with all the Collabnames.
Dim arrayCOLLABNAME(59) As String
Dim idx As Integer
idx = 0
Sheets("COLLABNAME").Select
Range("A1").Select
Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset((idx), 0) = ""
    arrayCOLLABNAME(idx) = ActiveCell.Offset(idx, 0).Value
    idx = idx + 1
Loop
```

---

```
'The name of the First Sheet
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
'Loop for 60 Sheets
For i = 0 To 60
    'adds the new Sheet
    Sheets.Add
    rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like '" & arrayCOLLABNAME(idx) & "' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn
    'use the new Sheet for inserting the Data
    With ActiveSheet
        col = 0
        'First Row: names of columns
        Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData

    End With
    rs.Close
Next i
```

Comment: It says SQL statement not properly ended at line ---rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS from TABLE_NAME AND COLLABNAME like 'COLLAB_NAME" & i + 1 & "' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC", cn

All the 60 collabnames are different and there is no pattern in their names

Comment: ah ok. Do you have a List or Something where all names of the Collabnames are? Or a Logic or anything else?

Comment: I have got the list of all the collabnames, some of them are:
CBAdjustmentSync_SAP_to_HHT,
CBAstroBatchMasterSync_SAP_ASTRO,
CBAstroConfirm_Astro_to_SAP,
CBAstroMaterialMasterSync_SAP_To_Astro_01,
CBAstroMaterialMasterSync_SAP_To_Astro_02,
CBAstroMaterialMasterSync_SAP_To_Astro_03,
CBAstroMaterialMasterSync_SAP_To_Astro_04,
CBAstroOrderStatusSync_Astro_01_To_SAP,
CBAstroOrderStatusSync_Astro_02_To_SAP,
CBAstroOrderStatusSync_Astro_03_To_SAP,
CBAstroProductionExecutionSync_SAP_To_Astro_01
.
.
.

Comment: Ok, i Edit the Code above. All you have to do now is, to insert a new Sheet, Rename it to "COLLABNAME" and insert in the Row A all the collabnames.

Comment: Thx for the quick replies,
Still its saying SQL command not ended properly.

Comment: I have edited my entire new code above. Also I renamed a sheet to COLLABNAME and in ROW A wrote all the collabnames

Comment: Ok, i'm not the Best with SQL, but is "AND COLLABNAME like" Right??
can you try out once "where COLLABNAME like"...
then the Error says The SQL statement ends with an inappropriate clause.

Comment: I am getting this error :
Run-time error '3021'
Either BOR or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record at line "mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)"

Comment: Ok, it think the Problem is that the Pinter is at the Last Position. Try bevor "mtxData=" "rs.MoveFirst" Hope that helps

Comment: When I changed and ran the macro it populated 100 sheets but no data in any one of them , when I reran the macro the number of sheets got increased and no data :(

Comment: Can you please go through the entire code I posted and arrange it and give it to me. That will be very helpful.

Comment: @User - you are using `like` in your query, which will treat the underscore characters in your collabnames as single-character wildcards.  That's probably **not** what you want, so you should be using `=` instead of `like`.  Also check out the `CopyFromRecordset` method to get your data onto the worksheet.